# Is it possible to un-capitalize text with CSS, and then re-capitalize it?

Tags: css

I have a piece of text coming to me from an external source that is ALL CAPS. I want it to be simply capitalized at the first letter. Seems that `text-transform:capitalize` won't uncapitalize the rest of the word. Any way to do this without JS?

Comment: Capitalize **every** word in your text or just the **first** one?

Comment: Which server side language are you using ?

Answer (score 7):

Something like this? http://jsbin.com/agocu3/2

**css**

```
   p { text-transform: lowercase;}
   p:first-letter {text-transform:capitalize}
```

**html**

```
<p>YOUR TEXT GOES HERE</p>
```

Comment: This is not what `capitalize` does: "Transforms the first character of each word to uppercase". This will only transform the first letter of the paragraph.

Comment: As you can see he transforms the text to lowercase first and then selects the first letter and capitalizes it. Click on the example he gave or look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/fbzr3/

Comment: The first letter of the first word, but not the other words of the string. So it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the text in lowercase and then use the pseudo selector :first-letter to uppercase the first letter

```
p {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

p:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CSS just use this:

http://www.convertcase.net/

Much cleaner and a lot of processing taken off the browser.

Comment: why use a service when you can do it through css? also, just **in case** they have an api, it still would take a lot of time to send text and get it back, process the response and display it, nullifying your premise of reducing the processing load.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a server side language:

Do lowercase using server-side language to the text you want to capitalize and then use css property on that element to capitalize.

This is how it worked for me:

**Server Side language: VB.net**
Inside a repeater - data coming from Database

```
<span class="capitalize"><%# Eval("RecipientFirstName").ToString.ToLower()%></span>
```

Converted into lowercase

**CSS**

```
.capitalize{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```